# Sphere - sphere collision detection -> reaction

Tags: algorithm, geometry, collision-detection, collision

I need to make an algorithm that detects when two spheres collide, and, the direction that wich one will take an instant after the collision.

Let say, Imagine like when you open your table in a pool match, all the balls are colliding one to another "randomly".

So, before starting to write the code myself, I was thinking if there is already a implementation of this out there.

Thx in advance!

Cyas.-

Comment: The most difficult part is the spin ...

Comment: I dont care about the spin, I only need colissions and "flat reactions".

Comment: The direction is simply along the line connecting the centres.

Answer (score 13):

The collision part is easy. Check if the distance between the spheres centers is less than the sum of their radius.

As for the bounce, you need to swap the velocity amounts that contribute to the total velocity perpendicular to the collision of the spheres. (Assuming all your spheres have equal mass, it would be different for a combination of different masses)

```
struct Vec3 {
    double x, y, z;
}

Vec3 minus(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) {
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = v1.x - v2.x;
    r.y = v1.y - v2.y;
    r.z = v1.z - v2.z;
    return r;
}

double dotProduct(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) {
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z;
}

Vec3 scale(const Vec3& v, double a) {
    Vec3 r;
    r.x = v.x * a;
    r.y = v.y * a;
    r.z = v.z * a;
    return r;
}

Vec3 projectUonV(const Vec3& u, const Vec3& v) {
    Vec3 r;
    r = scale(v, dotProduct(u, v) / dotProduct(v, v));
    return r;
}

int distanceSquared(const Vec3& v1, const Vec3& v2) {
    Vec3 delta = minus(v2, v1);
    return dotProduct(delta, delta);
}

struct Sphere {
    Vec3 position;
    Vec3 velocity;
    int radius;
}

bool doesItCollide(const Sphere& s1, const Sphere& s2) {
    int rSquared = s1.radius + s2.radius;
    rSquared *= rSquared;
    return distanceSquared(s1.position, s2.position) < rSquared;
}

void performCollision(Sphere& s1, Sphere& s2) {
    Vec3 nv1; // new velocity for sphere 1
    Vec3 nv2; // new velocity for sphere 2
    // this can probably be optimised a bit, but it basically swaps the velocity amounts
    // that are perpendicular to the surface of the collistion.
    // If the spheres had different masses, then u would need to scale the amounts of
    // velocities exchanged inversely proportional to their masses.
    nv1 = s1.velocity;
    nv1 += projectUonV(s2.velocity, minus(s2.position, s1.position));
    nv1 -= projectUonV(s1.velocity, minus(s1.position, s2.position));
    nv2 = s2.velocity;
    nv2 += projectUonV(s1.velocity, minus(s2.position, s1.position));
    nv2 -= projectUonV(s2.velocity, minus(s1.position, s2.position));
    s1.velocity = nv1;
    s2.velocity = nv2;
}
```

EDIT: If you need more accuracy, then upon a collision you should calculate how far to move both the colliding spheres backwards so that they just touch each other, then trigger the perform collision function. That would insure the angles will be more accurate.

Comment: Works great - but I think there's a problem: I start with 10 balls (none overlapping), where only one has velocity - after a little while and a lot of bouncing they're all moving. At interval I sum up all the velocities (abs(x) + abs(y)) - if I started out with, say 8 in all, it quickly grows (which must violate one of the conservation laws?) but after a while it stops growing, just fluctuates around 20.. I'm confused AND not sure if I should be.. (Note: after a collision is detected I move the first ball backward, in minute steps, until they no longer overlap, before calling performCollision)

Comment: Try summing up (sqrt(vx^2 + vy^2)) for each.