# C++ Checking For Two Spheres Intersecting/Collidiing

Tags: geometry, collision

Im getting into C++ and I have been researching how to have two spheres interact with one another. Much of what I have found was very complex or was actual math formulas. Is there any more simplistic way of creating a function that will recognize when any side of the sphere makes contact with another? Im not asking you to do my work, but I would really appreciate some kind of clean visual, pseudo code or or code snippet, that could help me understand more. Or maybe some links I havent found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the distance between the spheres' centers is less than the sum of their radii.

```
class Sphere {
public:
    double centerX, centerY, centerZ, radius;
    // .... 
};

double distanceBetween( const Sphere& a, const Sphere& b ) {
    return sqrt( pow( a.centerX - b.centerX, 2 ) + pow( a.centerY - b.centerY, 2 ) + pow( a.centerZ - b.centerZ, 2 ) );
}

bool areColliding( const Sphere& a, const Sphere& b ) {
    return distanceBetween( a, b ) < ( a.radius + b.radius );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post has a good explanation of how two spheres can interact with each other [Sphere - sphere collision detection -> reaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232318/sphere-sphere-collision-detection-reaction). Note that you'll likely have to deal with the complex math in order to solve this problem. Hopefully through reading these explanations you can gain a better understanding of what the math is supposed to be doing. I've found in the past it's best to try and visualize and understand how to solve a problem generally speaking before delving into the math.

Comment: You've given a 2D solution to what is clearly a 3D problem. I'm tempted to downvote you, but I'd rather have you edit your post instead.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't realize OP was talking about spheres.